# Testing graphql fieldresolver implementation

Tags: typescript, testing, jestjs, graphql, typegraphql

I would like to write a test in jest that checks if the all the field resolvers have been implemented.

Lets assume I have the following schema:

```js
@ObjectType()
class Ingredients{
  @Field(type => ID)
  id: string;

  @Field(type => [Recipe])
  recipes: Recipe[];
}


@ObjectType()
class Recipe {
  @Field(type => ID)
  id: string;

  @Field(type => [String])
  ingredients: string[];

  @Field(type => Author)
  author: Author;
}

@ObjectType()
class Author{
  @Field(type => ID)
  id: string;

  @Field(type => [Recipe])
  recipes: Recipe[];
}
```

If the recipe resolver is written in such a way that database automatically loads all relations then the following query will succeed:

```
query {
  recipes {
    id,
    ingredients {
      id
    }
    author {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

However if it does not have a field resolver for author, the following query would fail:

```
query {
  ingredients {
    id,
    recipes {
      id
      author {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I write a test that checks if the necessary field resolvers have been implemented? The test would ideally not depend on the ingredients query - else I could just check if that query succeeds but that would be too dependent on other things. Also, is there a way in which the test can detect automatically which fields would need a field resolver, e.g. by understanding when a field refers to another ObjectType?